# Stored procedure return results into temp table in another stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

What I want to do is insert new transaction that is a copy of the latest transaction but change couple of the values.

I have SP that returning the latest transaction given the request id called `sp_Get_YellowCard_Request_Last_Transaction`

I have another SP that I want to use the above called `sp_Update_CC_Move_YCR_TO`.

But since the `sp_Get_YellowCard_Request_Last_Transaction` returns a lot of fields (26) I don't want to specify all of them and just insert the result of it into temporary table and later change some field, and finally insert the temp table into the destination transaction table.

what i'v writter so far is:

```
USE [YellowCard_NewDesign]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Update_CC_Move_YCR_TO]    Script Date: 02/26/2013 09:43:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Update_CC_Move_YCR_TO]
    @YellowCard_Request_ID int,
    @yc_changer_username nvarchar(MAX),
    @yc_changer_rolename nvarchar(MAX),
    @yc_new_status nvarchar(MAX)
AS
    INSERT INTO #last_transaction
    EXEC dbo.sp_Get_YellowCard_Request_Last_Transaction @YellowCard_Request_ID*
```

I'm getting an error that #last_transaction is not defined.

How can I complete my SP without defining the temporary table fields?

Comment: Please indicate the type of SQL database used.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure

Comment: How and when are you calling those stored procs? The calls need to be in the same transaction for the temp table to survive.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2000, I used the following trick:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#last_transaction') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE #last_transaction(
        ....
    )

INSERT INTO #last_transaction
    EXEC ...
```

For later versions of SQL Server, I'd prefer table-valued functions.